# Отправка формы на сервер Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Я отправляю форму на сервер Node, и после отправки загружается пустая страница в браузере, в конце находится URL обработчика формые а не страница с контактамие с которой отправляю форму, как следствие загружается пустая страница.

Как сделать так, чтобы после отправки формы оставалась страница, с которой отправляю форму, то есть страница с контактами, а не пустая страница?

Пример кода сервера:

```
app.use('/handler', bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/handler', function(req, res, next) {
    // это обработчик на сервере, после отправки формы url заканчивается на "/handler"
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
});
```

HTML разметка:

```
<form action="/handler" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <!-- Набор полей формы -->
</form>
```

Comment: код в студию, мы же не телепаты

Comment: app.use('/handler', bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));



app.post('/handler', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
});

ето обработчик на сервере,после отправки формы url заканчивается на "/handler"

Comment: форма отправляется классическим form submit через POST?

Comment: да, <form action="/handler" method="POST" id="myForm">

Comment: поведение браузера при отправке формы на сервер через submit аналогично переходу по ссылке, т.е. браузер ожидает от сервера новый контент (например, HTML) для отображения.

Чтобы отправить данные без перезагрузки текущей страницы, используйте XHR, например, `jQuery.post`

Comment: а точнее, забирать " post " из формы ?

Comment: Извините, а как Вы получаете данные из этого $.post ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример сабмита формы на сервер посредством XHR:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br>
  <br>
  Comment:<br>
  <textarea name="comment"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/handler", $(this).serialize());
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: все сработало спасиба)))

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. После обработки запроса верните редирект.

Вариант 2. Используйте AJAX.